# Magento - Cannot send headers, headers already sent controllers/AccountController.php, line 252

Tags: php, magento

Having a bit of issues after a customer registers. The registration is going fine and all the data is being submitted but after a customer registers they are getting hit with this is in the face

"Cannot send headers; headers already sent in /customers/b/5/f/smkdwholesale.com/httpd.www/app/code/community/Exinent/CustomerActivation/controllers/AccountController.php, line 252"

I've had a look at the code and can't seem to find the issue. Here it is:

```
} catch (Exception $e) {
echo $e->getMessage(); // line 252
Mage::log($e->getMessage());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

```
catch (Exception $e) {
echo $e->getMessage(); // line 252
Mage::log($e->getMessage());
}
```

to

```
catch (Exception $e) {
    //echo $e->getMessage(); // line 252
    Mage::log($e->getMessage());
    }
```

because `echo` stop the page to redirect another page. you can check your error log in `var/log` folder.